# Calculate string matching percentage in a python list

Tags: python, string

I have a list with texts where I want to extract a percentage on how similar 
they are between [0,1]. Here is my code:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

listA = ['aaa','sss','ba']
listB = ['aa','aa']

def compare_strings(mylist):
  if (len(mylist) < 2):
    return 0.00
  else:
    cnt = 0
    total = 0.0
    for i in range(len(mylist)): 
        for j in range(i + 1, len(mylist)): 
            val = SequenceMatcher(None, mylist[i], mylist[j]).ratio()
            total += val 
            cnt += 1
    return (total / cnt)

print( "Sting simalarity in list 1 is %.5f" % (compare_strings(listA)))
print( "Sting simalarity in list 2 is %.5f" % (compare_strings(listB)))
>>>
Sting simalarity in list 1 is 0.13333
Sting simalarity in list 2 is 1.00000
```

This code is functional but I don't like as it seems a little complicated. Is there a better or a more elegant way to solve this problem? Is there a way to express this with the lambda operator?

Comment: This question seems more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have it, with one lambda function in a single line. Numpy mean is optional (you can implement your own mean)

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import numpy as np
import itertools

listA = ['aaa','sss','ba']
listB = ['aa','aa']


similarity = lambda x: np.mean([SequenceMatcher(None, a,b).ratio() for a,b in itertools.combinations(x, 2)])

similarity(listA)
#> 0.13333333333333333
similarity(listB)
#> 1.0
```

Comment: Nice, but you could unpack `pair` to `a, b` or `p1, p2` instead. Also, using `def` instead of `lambda` would be better style.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks! done. About the `def`, i just provided a lambda because that's what the problem stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get all the combinations and then use `sum`, and calculate the number of combinations directly instead of counting them.

```
def compare_strings(mylist):
    if len(mylist) < 2: return 0.0
    total = sum(SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() for a, b in combinations(mylist, 2))
    cnt = (len(mylist) * (len(mylist)-1)) // 2
    return total / cnt
```